# How to filter out common array in array of arrays

Tags: javascript

I have an array of arrays:

```
[
  [
    "Serta",
    "Black Friday"
  ],
  [
    "Serta",
    "Black Friday"
  ],
  [
    "Simmons",
    "Black Friday"
  ],
  [
    "Simmons",
    "Black Friday"
  ],
  [
    "Simmons",
    "Black Friday"
  ],
  [
    "Simmons",
    "Black Friday"
  ]
]
```

I need to get unique arrays only, like:

```
[
  [
    "Serta",
    "Black Friday"
  ],
  [
    "Simmons",
    "Black Friday"
  ] 
]
```

I know that for single array element I can use `.filter()` like:

```
array.filter((d,i)=>array.indexOf(d)==i)
```

but I'm not sure for this case, without any library like lodash.

Comment: I want to ask for array of arrays that is different @Alexis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a [JSON](http://json.org/) string as key of the array in a hash table and filter with it.

```js
var data = [["Serta", "Black Friday"], ["Serta", "Black Friday"], ["Simmons", "Black Friday"], ["Simmons", "Black Friday"], ["Simmons", "Black Friday"], ["Simmons", "Black Friday"]],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = data.filter(a => !hash[JSON.stringify(a)] && (hash[JSON.stringify(a)] = true));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This may break for entries containing the joining character.

Comment: @Cerbrus, not with a json as key.

Comment: Now that the `.join` is edited out, this seems ok.